# Using socket to visit a localhost website. Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, http

I am using socket to visit a localhost website. Get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The socket code as below:

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('0.0.0.0',8080))

mysock.send('GET http://localhost:8080/hello HTTP/1.0\r\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    print data
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP request header should end with two newlines. If you send only one blank line, the server will wait until timeout.

```
mysock.send('GET http://localhost:8000/hello HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
```